# jstree refresh tree with response data

Tags: jstree

My first question why I cant get into 'check_node.jstree' event although I check a checkbox in tree..
And second. Here is my tree definition each time I click expand button which trigger 'before_open.jstree' event and refresh tree with new datas.. but after it rebuild tree it triggs the the event again and post to server.. how can I just refresh tree then stop the work.

```
$('#tree_2').jstree({
    'plugins': ["checkbox","types","json_data" ,"ui"],
    'core': {
        "themes" : {
            "responsive": true,
            "icons":true
        },
        'data': [{}]
    },
    "types" : {
        "default" : {
            "icon" : "fa fa-folder icon-state-warning icon-lg"
        },
        "file" : {
            "icon" : "fa fa-file icon-state-warning icon-lg"
        }
    }

}).bind('check_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    debugger
    alert("check_node.jstree")
}).bind('before_open.jstree', function (e, datap) {
     $.ajax({
     url: "../../Controller/ActiveDirectoryController.php5",
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     data: datap.node.text,//selected node text
     success: function (result) {
         debugger
         if(result.Objects.length>0)
         {
             passOpen=false;
             treeData_ = prepareObjectsforTree(result.Objects);
             resfreshJSTree(treeData_);

         }

     },
     error: function (a, b, c) {

     }
     })

})
```

and rebuild jstree with response data:

```
function resfreshJSTree(treeDataa) {
    $('#tree_2').jstree(true).settings.core.data = treeDataa;
    $('#tree_2').jstree("refresh");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`check_node.jstree` will only fire if `checkbox.tie_selection` is set to `false` in your config. If it is not - listen for `select_node.jstree` (or `changed.jstree`).

As for the second question - do not implement lazy loading this way - please read the docs on lazy loading - that is not the way to achieve it.